# Dealing with multiple sprite directories in Compass/SASS

Tags: css, sass

We have 2 directories for sprites and I would like to use both of them in Compass. I tried doing relative imports like so:
`@import ../../../../../foo/bar/sprites/*.png`

Compass runs without error, but the outputted sprite is an invalid image. How do you deal with multiple sprite directories? Can you set Compass config parameters in SASS files?

Comment: Does this work when you only have 1 sprite directory, or is the problem actually because you're trying to have 2?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. I wouldn't need the `../`s if I only have 1 sprite directory. Since Compass uses the directory as part of the output path, I would be surprised if the `../`s worked.

Comment: Your question implies that the problem is you have multiple sprite directories, did you check to see if the problem is with sprites in general with only 1 directory?

Comment: Sprites work fine. There's recently a need to use a second directory, and that's the issue.